# A Python interview question which I faced

Tags: python-3.x

The question is to print the numbers mentioned below without using any conditional statements? The set of numbers are var=01120221011202210112. Is there a way to do the same without using conditional statements ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to clarify if part of the task was to generate that output via a loop, such that a single print statement isn't the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the above pattern a number is always the sum of its previous 2 numbers modulo 3
So its a sequence with a(0)=0,a(1)=1 and a(n)=(a(n-1)+a(n-2))%3 for n>=2

```
x=0
y=1
print("01",end='')
for i in range(18):
    z=(x+y)%3
    print(z,end='')
    x=y
    y=z
```

Answer (score 0):

> > > a='1011'
> > >
> > > b='2022'
> > >
> > > s = a+b+a+b+a+b
> > >
> > > s[1:-3]

'01120221011202210112'